# Magento2 users in the backend website scope

Tags: magento2.3

I have 3 websites under one Magento, 
how can I give separate login for each store for admin users?
should Every store should be managed separately from the backend and frontend
also USERS and ROLES Should be separate and related to every store alone

I'm new to Magento

Answer (score 0):

You either need the Enterprise Edition or install an extension https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-admin-permissions/ or code it yourself if these solutions don't fullfill your requirments.